# I want to use a fixed effects model on a regression with one variable being the group variable

Tags: r, regression, lm

I am using felm() and the code is running on all the model… but I need it to run on state only… the problem asks "Estimate the model using fixed effects (FE) at the state level". Using felm() is not getting me the correct results because I don't know if I need to include state as a dependent variable (doesn't give me correct answers) or how to specify that one variable needs to be the group variable (I'm assuming this is how to get accurate results).

I have tried using

```
plm(ind~depvar+state,data=data, model='within')
```

I have tried using

```
felm(ind~depvar+state,data=data)


FELinMod3<-felm(DRIVING$totfatrte~DRIVING$D81+DRIVING$state, data=DRIVING)

FELinMod3<-plm(DRIVING$totfatrte~DRIVING$D81+DRIVING$state, data=DRIVING, model='within')
```

output is giving me incorrect coefficients to the ones I know are correct in STATA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like `felm()` is for when you have multiple grouping variables, but it sounds like you're using only one grouping variable for fixed effects? (i.e., state).

you should get the same correct result for

```
mod3 <- lm(totfatrte ~ D81 + state, data = DRIVING)
```

Also, if the coefficients or standard errors disagree between stata and R, that doesn't necessarily mean that R is wrong.

Reading the [documentation for felm()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lfe/versions/2.8-3/topics/felm) indicates that your code should look more like this:

```
model3<-felm(totfatrte ~ D81 | state, data = DRIVING)
```

but the code specifications for it are pretty complex based on whether you want to cluster your standard errors and so on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's perfect! I ran it and it worked out perfectly!

Comment: Model3 worked perfectly. I'm assuming that's how you group the single variable when running felm

Comment: sounds good. I encourage you to thoroughly read the linked documentation though. I've never bothered with felm() because it doesn't annoy me to have coefficients listed for large groups of Fixed Effects.